# Using Canvas in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: windows, html, canvas, html5-canvas, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am developing a windows phone html5 application. I am using a canvas tag in my code.
However I get an error saying canvas is an invalid child. Any ideas on how to fix this will be appreciated

My code is shown below:

```
 <div class="imagebox">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: solid 1pt black; margin-top: 15px;">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

The error being show is:

```
The element 'div' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' has invalid child element 'canvas' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'. List of possible elements expected: 'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, ul, ol, dl, pre, hr, blockquote, address, fieldset, table, form, a, br, span, bdo, map, object, img, tt, i, b, big, small, em, strong, dfn, code, q, samp, kbd, var, cite, abbr, acronym, sub, sup, input, select, textarea, label, button, noscript, ins, del, script' in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'.
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: What is the DTD on your page? Are you sure it is HTML5? What are you using to develop?